# Two JSESSIONIDs from the same page (Java, Servlet, Jersey, Ajax jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, struts2, jersey

I'm developing a three layer application with web services exposing underlaying business methods. Web services are implemented with Jersey in RESTful style and the layer is protected by a filter which implements *com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilterFactory*: in this filter I have implemented my custom authorization mechanism. All this is packaged in a web application that I will call *backend*. I know that lot of you will criticize this because web services are stateless for nature, but we are speaking of a bank context and everything must be checked and authorized. So please forgive me :-P

Then I have an other distinct application (the client) which makes async requests to the backend, all this requests have to be pre-authorized by the backend itself.

This client makes requests in two ways:

- The first is via Struts 2 in an action (login)
- Second way is via jQuery ajax (generic data retrieving)

The problem in this scenario is that when the first call via Struts2 is made (login) the backend opens a session, otherwise when all the jQuery ajax calls are made the backend opens another session. The result is that all the jQuery ajax calls are not authorized because the authentication is made in two different sessions. What I want to achieve is to use the same session for all kind of calls, considering that the calls happen from the same client.

Any idea ?

-

Alex

Comment: Are the jQuery requests going against Struts2 actions?

Comment: If I understood well the question. do you mean struts2 actions as endpoints for the jQuery ajax requests ? jQuery async requests are made to Jersey web services directly from javascript code.

Comment: If you want the rest services and actions to share a session, perhaps you could refactor to the the [Struts2 Rest Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html).  Authentication in a traditional Restful service such as Jersey JAX-RS should be done using a secure signature mechanism such as [OAuth](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/OAuth).

Comment: Yeah, I mean make the jQuery requests go against Struts2 actions. You don't need a web service just to respond to ajax requests. Rees is right in that trying to use a traditional HTTP session in a web service is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok thanks very much. OAuth is a mechanism I used for a Twitter client for Android, I think it is a good idea. So we are saying that both kind of requests (from Struts2 actions and from jQuery ajax) will be secured/signed by OAuth protocol. Is it possibile to associate object values to OAuth authorized request like traditional session ?